# How is the overflow removed from this?

Tags: html, css, overflow

How do I remove the overflow from this?

All it is is a toggle button.

You click on it and it goes on and off.

https://jsfiddle.net/br93hux6/

I can't figure out how to do this.

Everything I have tried has not worked.

That is all I am trying to do, remove the overflow.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

How is this able to be done?

[image]

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  const onOffButton = document.querySelector(".switch");

  function switchButton() {
    onOffButton.classList.toggle("on");
  }
  onOffButton.addEventListener("click", switchButton);
})();
```

```css
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 195px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black, inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c, inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.switch.on .button {
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px #ff1818;
}

.switch.on .button .light {
  animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}

.switch.on .button .shine {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch.on .button .shadow {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch .button {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: center center -20px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #9b0621;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient( #980000 0%, #6f0000 30%, #6f0000 70%, #980000 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .button::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 30%, #650000 75%, #320000) 50% 50%/97% 97%, #b10000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.switch .button::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#650000, #320000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.switch .light {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: light-off 1s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ffc97e, #ff1818 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.switch .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(transparent 30%, rgba(101, 0, 0, 0.7) 70%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.switch .characters {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%, radial-gradient( circle, transparent 50%, white 52%, white 70%, transparent 72%) 50% 80%/33% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes light-off {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="shine"></div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "remove overflow" you mean "remove the scrollbars", simply apply `overflow:hidden` to `body`:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  const onOffButton = document.querySelector(".switch");

  function switchButton() {
    onOffButton.classList.toggle("on");
  }
  onOffButton.addEventListener("click", switchButton);
})();
```

```css
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 195px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 1px 2px black, inset 0 2px 2px -2px white, inset 0 0 2px 15px #47434c, inset 0 0 2px 22px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 700px;
}

.switch.on .button {
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(25deg);
  box-shadow: 0 -10px 20px #ff1818;
}

.switch.on .button .light {
  animation: flicker 0.2s infinite 0.3s;
}

.switch.on .button .shine {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch.on .button .shadow {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch .button {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: center center -20px;
  transform: translateZ(20px) rotateX(-25deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background-color: #9b0621;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient( #980000 0%, #6f0000 30%, #6f0000 70%, #980000 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .button::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 30%, #650000 75%, #320000) 50% 50%/97% 97%, #b10000;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.switch .button::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: linear-gradient(#650000, #320000);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 50px 8px 0px black, 0 80px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.switch .light {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: light-off 1s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#ffc97e, #ff1818 40%, transparent 70%);
}

.switch .dots {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(transparent 30%, rgba(101, 0, 0, 0.7) 70%);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}

.switch .characters {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white) 50% 20%/5% 20%, radial-gradient( circle, transparent 50%, white 52%, white 70%, transparent 72%) 50% 80%/33% 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shine {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(white, transparent 3%) 50% 50%/97% 97%, linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), transparent 50%, transparent 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)) 50% 50%/97% 97%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.switch .shadow {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes light-off {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <div class="button">
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="characters"></div>
    <div class="shine"></div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing that here removes vertical scroll. https://jsfiddle.net/3kafbrwq/

Comment: @htmlcsscoding hmm... Replace `overflow:hidden` with `overflow-x:hidden`